# Error updating emacs packages: Failed to download 'gnu' archive

Tags: emacs, checksum, elpa, melpa

My `init.el` uses this to initialize packages:

```
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

When I do `M-x package-refresh-contents` I get the following error: `` Failed to download `gnu' archive. ``

`M-x toggle-debug-on-error` gives me this stacktrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig: (\"No public key for 474F05837FBDEF9B created at 2014-09-29T07:20:03-0700 using DSA\")")
  signal(error ("Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig: (\"No public key for 474F05837FBDEF9B created at 2014-09-29T07:20:03-0700 using DSA\")"))
  error("Failed to verify signature %s: %S" "archive-contents.sig" ("No public key for 474F05837FBDEF9B created at 2014-09-29T07:20:03-0700 using DSA"))
  package--check-signature("http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/" "archive-contents")
  package--download-one-archive(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") "archive-contents")
```

Is this a problem with my configuration, and how would I fix it?

Comment: [Same question on Emacs StackExchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-to-proceed-on-package-el-signature-check-failure) has more information.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like a bug in your version of Emacs.  You can probably circumvent it by setting `package-check-signature` to nil.

Comment: I'm on Version 24.3.50 (9.0). Would upgrading Emacs help? Is there a newer downloadable build for Mac OS X?

Comment: 24.3.50 means "some snapshot of the code during the development of 24.4".  We moved on to 24.3.90 around april, so your snapshot is ancient by now (a snapshot older than a month is already "old") and deserves to be retired.

Comment: On 24.3.93 and it works great now, thank you! No more scary red "UNSIGNED" tags in the package list.

Comment: Here same problem with emacs-24.4 in Fedora 21

Comment: had the same issue and fixed it by upgrading emacs - used emacs 24.3 before, upgraded to https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port (emacs 24.5.1 for now) and the issue is gone

Comment: [this is a problem with elpa](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-12/msg00781.html), not with emacs

Answer (score 24):

This is not an error caused by misconfiguration but is due to the change of the file `package-keyring.gpg` from Emacs 26.3.  As stated from the release [note](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/emacs.html#Releases):

```
New GPG key for GNU ELPA package signature checking.
```

I believe the newer packages from GNU ELPA [repository](http://elpa.gnu.org/) are signed for this new keyring to check.

The simple way to fix it is to upgrade to Emacs 26.3.

But if you were like me, who don't bother to upgrade, you can download the `package-keyring.gpg` file from [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/etc/package-keyring.gpg?h=emacs-26.3) and put it in the `etc/` directory under your Emacs installation location.  In my case, it is `/usr/local/share/emacs/26.1/etc/package-keyring.gpg`.  It might be different locations for different installation methods (apt, yum, etc.) on various platforms (macOS, Windows, etc.).

Alternatively, you can try to install the package [gnu-elpa-keyring-update](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/gnu-elpa-keyring-update.html) to automatically update the keyring in the future.

Comment: Do you by any chance know a solution that works without root privileges?

Comment: Of course, you can install [gnu-epla-keyring-update](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/gnu-elpa-keyring-update.html) or follow the instructions from the README of that package. But I believe that the effective directory is on `~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg`.

Comment: I am on Emacs 26.3 and I still get this error.

Answer (score 17):

For anyone else that doesn't have the signature problem, try to initialise package

`M-x package-initialize`

Comment: this was the only solution to my problem; _not_ installing `gnutls`, `gnupg`, changing `https` to `http`, or adding a `/` after `packages`

Comment: This helped. Does anyone one know what causes the state that is fixed by initializing packages?

Answer (score 13):

My issue was that I was missing gpg (gnupg).

On OSX I solved this by using `brew install gpg`.

Comment: The code should work just fine without `gpg` (it will just skip checking the signatures), so this is still a problem that needs to be solved.  If you can reproduce it, please `M-x report-emacs-bug` providing as many details as you can.

Comment: Bug is #19409 (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-12/msg00781.html); if I understand correctly ELPA has been broken since September, 2014 (at least) because some joker signed a package with a key that they didn't publish... And nobody seems to care.

Answer (score 0):

I installed emacs on Arch Linux, opened it, ran `package-refresh-contents` and got this issue. After a while, I realized I had no init file. If this is your case, create your init file with `emacs ~/.emacs.d/init.el` and then add the following content:

```
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

Save it with `C-x C-s` and run `package-refresh-contents` again. This time it will work.

Comment: `failed to download melpa`, `failed to download gnu`